# problema generar tabla dinamica android studio

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, tabla-dinámica

tengo un problema con Android Studio, ya que me repite las tablas dos veces en algunos dispositivos y en otros no, el código genera 3 tablas con distinta información, pero en ciertos dispositivos se repiten las mismas, quedando 6 como resultado, si alguien me pudiese orientar, se lo agradecería, adjunto el código. Cómo nota aparte, hay dos clases más, uno para crear un pdf de lo que se ve en pantalla y otro para enviarlo como adjunto por mail , pero esos funcionan bien.

```
public class principal1 extends Activity {

//Directorios y rutas
String carpeta = "/pdf";
File sdCard, directory = null;
String archivo;
String pdf;

//var de envio
Boolean error=false;
//variables datepicker
private static final String CERO = "0";
private static final String BARRA = "-";

//Calendario para obtener fecha & hora
public final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

//variables fecha
final int mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
final int dia = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
final int anio = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

ButtonRectangle btn_mail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal1);
    btn_mail = (ButtonRectangle) findViewById(R.id.btn_mail);
    obtenerFecha();

    btn_mail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            btn_mail.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            try {
                tomafoto();
                manipulatePdf();
                sendMail();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void obtenerFecha() {
    DatePickerDialog recogerFecha = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            final int mesActual = month + 1;
            String diaFormateado = (dayOfMonth < 10) ? CERO + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) : String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
            String mesFormateado = (mesActual < 10) ? CERO + String.valueOf(mesActual) : String.valueOf(mesActual);
            String etFecha = year + BARRA + mesFormateado + BARRA + diaFormateado;
            SharedPreferences setting = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(principal1.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = setting.edit();
            editor.putString("etFecha", etFecha);
            editor.commit();
            procesafecha();
        }
    }, anio, mes, dia);
    recogerFecha.show();
}
public void procesafecha() {
    Tabla tabla = new Tabla(this, (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabla));
    tabla.agregarCabecera(R.array.cabecera_tabla);
    SharedPreferences setting = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(principal1.this);
    String fecha_resumen = setting.getString("etFecha", "");
    String DateFormat = "";
    SQLiteHelper MDB = new SQLiteHelper(principal1.this);
    try {
        Tabla tabla2 = new Tabla(this, (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabla2));
        tabla2.agregarCabecera(R.array.cabecera_2);
        ArrayList elementos2 = new ArrayList();
        elementos2.add(MDB.report(fecha_resumen).getEquipo());
        elementos2.add(MDB.report(fecha_resumen).getTipo_faena());
        elementos2.add(MDB.report(fecha_resumen).getLugar_faena());
        elementos2.add(MDB.report(fecha_resumen).getOperador());
        tabla2.agregarFilaTabla(elementos2);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getCause();
        Tabla tabla2 = new Tabla(this, (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabla2));
        ArrayList elementos2 = new ArrayList();
        elementos2.add("Sin información");
        elementos2.add("Sin información");
        elementos2.add("Sin información");
        elementos2.add("Sin información");
        tabla2.agregarFilaTabla(elementos2);
    }

    try {
        long vi = MDB.r_valores_min(fecha_resumen).getTiempo_inicio();
        if (vi==0){
            Tabla tabla3 = new Tabla(this, (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabla3));
            tabla3.agregarCabecera(R.array.cabecera_3);
            ArrayList elementos3 = new ArrayList();
            elementos3.add("Sin información");
            elementos3.add("Sin información");
            elementos3.add("Sin información");
            elementos3.add("Sin información");
            elementos3.add("Sin información");
            tabla3.agregarFilaTabla(elementos3);
            btn_mail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            String DateFormat2 = formatter2.format(vi);
            String vci = MDB.r_valores_min(fecha_resumen).getTipo_control();
            String ci = MDB.r_valores_min(fecha_resumen).getValor_tipo_control();
            long vf = MDB.r_valores_max(fecha_resumen).getTiempo_termino();
            SimpleDateFormat formatter3 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            String DateFormat3 = formatter3.format(vf);
            String vcf = MDB.r_valores_max(fecha_resumen).getTipo_control();
            String cf = MDB.r_valores_max(fecha_resumen).getValor_tipo_control();
            long sv= vf-vi;
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            int millisec = 0, sec = 0, min = 0, hour = 0;
            long millislong = 0;
            millislong = sv;
            if (millislong > 1000) {
                sec = (int) (millislong / 1000);
                millisec = (int) millislong % 1000;
                if (sec >= 60) {
                    min = sec / 60;
                    sec = sec % 60;
                }
                if (min >= 60) {
                    hour = min / 60;
                    min = min % 60;
                }
                cal.clear();
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
                cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, sec);
                cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, millisec);
                DateFormat = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
            }
            SimpleDateFormat formatter4 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            String DateFormat4 = formatter3.format(sv);
            Tabla tabla3 = new Tabla(this, (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabla3));
            tabla3.agregarCabecera(R.array.cabecera_3);
            ArrayList elementos3 = new ArrayList();
            elementos3.add(DateFormat2);
            elementos3.add(DateFormat3);
            elementos3.add(DateFormat);
            elementos3.add(vci + ": " + ci);
            elementos3.add(vcf + ": " + cf);
            tabla3.agregarFilaTabla(elementos3);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getCause();
    }
    try {
        Integer cuenta_reg = MDB.getAllValuesRegistroProeq(1).size();
        ArrayList<String> elementos = new ArrayList();
        String actividad = "";
        String cuenta = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= cuenta_reg; i++) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            int millisec = 0, sec = 0, min = 0, hour = 0;
            long millislong = 0;
            millislong = MDB.Operacion(fecha_resumen).get(i).getSuma_tiempo();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = setting.edit();
            editor.putLong("mi_ope", MDB.Operacion(fecha_resumen).get(i).getSuma_tiempo());
            editor.commit();
            if (millislong > 1000) {
                sec = (int) (millislong / 1000);
                millisec = (int) millislong % 1000;
                if (sec >= 60) {
                    min = sec / 60;
                    sec = sec % 60;
                }
                if (min >= 60) {
                    hour = min / 60;
                    min = min % 60;
                }
                cal.clear();
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
                cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, sec);
                cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, millisec);
                DateFormat = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
                actividad = MDB.Operacion(fecha_resumen).get(i).getActividad();
                cuenta = MDB.Operacion(fecha_resumen).get(i).getCuenta_nombre().toString();
                elementos.add(fecha_resumen);
                elementos.add(actividad);
                elementos.add(cuenta);
                elementos.add(DateFormat);
                tabla.agregarFilaTabla(elementos);
            } else {
                elementos.add(fecha_resumen);
                elementos.add("Operación");
                elementos.add("0");
                elementos.add("00:00:00");
                tabla.agregarFilaTabla(elementos);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getCause();
    }
    try {
        setting = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(principal1.this);
        long ope = setting.getLong("mi_ope", 0);
        long millislong = ope;
        ArrayList<String> elementos = new ArrayList();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        int millisec = 0, sec = 0, min = 0, hour = 0;
        if (millislong > 1000) {
            sec = (int) (millislong / 1000);
            millisec = (int) millislong % 1000;
            if (sec >= 60) {
                min = sec / 60;
                sec = sec % 60;
            }
            if (min >= 60) {
                hour = min / 60;
                min = min % 60;
            }
            cal.clear();
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, sec);
            cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, millisec);
            DateFormat = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
            elementos.add(fecha_resumen);
            elementos.add("Todas");
            elementos.add("Total Jornada");
            elementos.add(DateFormat);
            tabla.agregarFilaTabla(elementos);
        } else {
            elementos.add(fecha_resumen);
            elementos.add("Todas");
            elementos.add("Total Jornada");
            elementos.add("Sin Información");
            tabla.agregarFilaTabla(elementos);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error estaba en la forma en que se llamaba la función, dentro del onCreate se reemplaza por las siguientes lineas y se soluciona el problema

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal4);
    btn_mail = (ButtonRectangle) findViewById(R.id.btn_mail);
    btn_report = (ButtonRectangle) findViewById(R.id.btn_report);
    obtenerFecha();
    btn_mail.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    btn_report.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            btn_report.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn_mail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            procesafecha();

        }
    });

    btn_mail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btn_mail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn_report.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            try {
                tomafoto();
                manipulatePdf();
                sendMail();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```